# how to control in permissions in database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Please, before anything, I hope anyone can help me.

I'am a beginner in this field.

I work on `myphpadmin`.

For my problem, I have two tables:

```
users(id,username,password,user_level)
chat(id,msg,users_id(fk))
```

Now I have 3 levels in the table `user`. In the application, when the user registers, it will be one of the three levels `(employee,manager,customers)`. **The `chat` table  must be between `employee` and `manager`, 
and `customers` can't use it.**

How can I mange this in my database and prevent customers from seeing chat?

Comment: anyone can help me , please?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a query against the users table checking to see if the current user has the right role.

```
SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE user_name = <name>;
```

From there you can use the returned result as a conditional to determine whether the user should be given access

Comment: i dont understand your query u write , should it be select user_level from users where user_level=???? , and if this wrong user_name=<name> what this mean ? and after do this query what should i do how will system in andriod application will understand how to stop customers from use chat

Comment: and how i can return result as conditonal to deterime user role?

Comment: The query I wrote will return 1 row, for the current user and have one field with their user_level. You can then read that value in your code with an `IF` statement, checking the user_level is only 'employee' or 'manager' before displaying the chat. The <name> is simply the current user's name, you can use id as well. You will presumably have these details have they have logged in

Comment: ok, as i understand from you first in write the query then in application code use if statement to check user_Level okay?

Comment: last question, in query after where you write user_name =<name> , i dont know what is the name the user will enter so can i use this " where user_level in(employee, manger)? instead of user_name in query? or this is wrong and by the way id is auto- increment

Comment: Do you know their ID? in that case use where id = <id>, basically use whatever info you have available to accurately determine which user record you want to access. Selecting by where user_role = role will return ALL users with that role, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: i have in application andriod login his data will save in users , the something that will be static in table is user_leverl will be between 3 only ( employee,customers, manger)

Comment: now after they registe and data save in table users , chat part will show , i want to show to employee, and manger only

Comment: and i dont know their id , it will be auto-increment , like first user take id=1, second user take id =2 , etc..

Comment: So if you don't know who the user is and have no way of finding out, how are you going to check if they have access to the chat? You can't check to see if an unknown user has rights